# Is this a vector space? Does this abide by the axioms of vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

So my question is this:

[image]

and I know the axioms for vector spaces are this:

[image]

So for this to be closed under addition, A and B both have to be vectors that fit the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & 1 \\ b & c \end{bmatrix} $$ and their sum also have to be in this form right?

So I think this is not closed under addition because:

if A = $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$ and
B = if A = $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 5 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$

A + B = if A = $\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 9 & 11 \end{bmatrix}$

which is no longer in the format. Is this right?

If that's true, I can find an example that shows it's not closed under multiplication either. Am I analyzing this correctly?

Comment: Correct, the set is not closed under addition, as your example shows. It's also not closed under scalar multiplication, e.g. try multiplying by a scalar other than $1$.

Comment: It’s lacking a $0$.

Comment: What do you mean @MichaelHoppe?

Comment: What’s the zero vector?

Comment: You have correctly found one of the four ways the set fails to satisfy the axioms. Now look for the other three. Closure (or not) under matrix multiplication is irrelevant.

Comment: Why is it irrelevant? Isn't it one of the axioms that isn't satisfied @EthanBolker

Comment: Do you see in the axioms a product *of vectors*?

Comment: Oh I should have said closed under scalar multiplication then?

Comment: Yes, closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found the first reason this fails to be a vector space; let me outline how to understand the other three:

- **Closure under addition**: As you've observed, if $A,B\in V$ then $A+B$ is *not* in $V$: the upper-right-hand entry of $A+B$ will be $2$, and $V$ consists only of matrices whose upper-right-hand entry is $1$.
- **Existence of an additive identity**: Suppose $A,B\in V$. What can you say about the upper-right-hand entry of $A+B$? Do you see why this means we can *never* have $A+B=A$ if $A,B\in V$ (think about what you know about the upper-right-hand entry of $A$ ...)? Do you see why this means that $V$ has no additive identity element?
- **Existence of additive inverses**: This one "comes pre-broken" once you've proved the previous bulletpoint - you can't have additive inverses without an additive identity!
- **Closure under scalar multiplication**: Suppose $\lambda$ is a scalar - that is, a real number - other than $1$. If $A\in V$, what can you say about the upper-right-hand entry of $\lambda A$? What does that say about whether $\lambda A$ is in $V$ or not? Why is that a problem?

  - Note that matrix multiplication is irrelevant here: the axioms for a vector space don't say anything about *multiplying vectors by vectors*, just *multiplying vectors by scalars*.

Comment: Great answer. What is the point btw of defining vector spaces as specifically as this problem does. IN the real world, where and why is this useful?

Comment: @Jwan622 - If you find a source that does not define vector spaces this "specifically", throw it away, as it is no good. The only thing there which is not always required for vector spaces is that the scalars are "real numbers". In general, vector spaces can be taken over other fields (most commonly, the complex numbers, but there are other possibilities). Vector spaces are probably the most widely applied subject of all higher mathematics. They are indispensible in physics, engineering, graphics, computing (search engines make extensive use) any any sort of statistical analysis.

Comment: @Jwan622 What do you mean by "x and y being over 0"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Sorry, I meant, are there common instances in the real world where we have to determine if matrices in the form of $\begin{bmatrix} a & 1 \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}$ are vector spaces? Are problems that specific in the sense that we have to determine vector spaces with a 1 in the top right corner?

Comment: @Jwan622 Well, what you've shown now is that they never are. However, we *do* often care about showing that some collection of objects is a vector space. The result we've (essentially) proved here - that the set $M$ of 2-by-2 matrices with complex entries (or indeed entries from any [field of scalars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))) with a $1$ in the upper-right-hand entry is not a vector space - should be thought of as an *example* of a kind of problem we care about.

Comment: Sure the specific example is not a vector space... but are we often trying to show that matrices in a similar format are or are not vector spaces in the real world? Why?